# Googlebot crawling multiple instances of the same URL with many slashes

Tags: google-crawlers

I work for a digital marketing and SEO company. One of our clients' website has the following issue:
when the site is crawled by Googlebot it reads multiple instances of the same URL with many slashes, for example:

```
/mortgage-calculators
/mortgage-calculators/
/mortgage-calculators//
/mortgage-calculators///
/mortgage-calculators////
/mortgage-calculators/////
/mortgage-calculators//////
/mortgage-calculators///////
/mortgage-calculators////////
/mortgage-calculators/////////
/mortgage-calculators//////////
/mortgage-calculators///////////
/mortgage-calculators////////////
/mortgage-calculators/////////////
/mortgage-calculators//////////////
```

The website is built with PHP MVC framework(not by our company). Unfortunately I'm not allowed to reveal the domain name of the client. I'd like to know what could be causing this problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Check the source for a misconfigured relative link or something that could be misinterpreted as a relative link. Other people had similar problems before: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/JlHcwcz1S_Q

Comment: Nothing unusual on the code except Cloudflare code at the very end of the page. Could this be causing problems?